# Why does [1,2,3,4,5].each {|n| puts n } generate an rspec Coverage Report (!)

Tags: ruby, rspec, block

I made a typo.  I meant to type this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each {|n| puts n}
```

But I typed this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each n { puts n }
```

I got:

```
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/...
```

The result from this second command was really suprising: I got an rspec coverage report!

What about the mistyped code made my system generate a coverage report?

Comment: You're not using Spring, Rspec, and TestUnit are you? There is a [GH Issue](https://github.com/jonleighton/spring/issues/103) related to running TestUnit before Rspec resulting in a coverage report being generated?

Comment: Which could be related to [an issue with the guard gem](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/issues/27) that causes rspec tests to always be run.

Comment: Haven't used rspec in a while, but have you checked if `n` is defined? Could be some helper method.

Comment: Thanks David, however I am not using Guard, Spring or TestUnit in this code.

Comment: Are you using the [SimpleCov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) gem?

Comment: more info needed, can't reproduce: undefined method `n' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4:0xb6f5f24c @example=nil>

Comment: `n` must be defined somehow. What gems are installed in the environment this code is running in?

Comment: Need to provide a reproduction case. How are you running your code?

Comment: What require statements do you have in your code? Please provide complete code you're running.